# My Ajax Code did't work

Tags: php, jquery

I'm not able to understand why the code is not working. I hope you guys will find the error and help me solve this. Thank you.

```
<form action="dashboard.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="error" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="alert alert-success" id="success" style="display:none"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginForm").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "functions.php",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        alert('submiting');
      },
      success: function(res) {
        alert(res);
        if (res == 1) {
          window.location.href = "dashboard.php";
          return true;
        } else {
          alert('wrong Username/password');
          return false;
        },
        error: function() {
          return false;
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you specify what problem you have? "Not work" is too broad.

Comment: There's thousands of reasons why this may not work. Have you at least checked the console to see if there's any errors? You also need to stop the form submission in the `submit` event handler.

Comment: If it`s on the same page as the form you need a preventDefault() in there

Comment: actually m Beginer in ajax so not getting exact. after submitiing form code cannot goes through ajax

Comment: Now that I've formatted your code correctly you can also see that you've put the `error` handler inside the `success` which is a syntax error. Also, redirecting after making an AJAX request makes the point of AJAX pretty redundant.

Comment: yeah you are right sir. i make the correction and its working .

Comment: sir its working but

Comment: its not entered in success part...so not able to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Your **event** submit is submitting the form instead going to Ajax.

You have to **prevent** the **event** of the form with: `e.preventDefault();`

Use like this:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //more code
```

Let me know if works.

Comment: its solved sir. thanks for giving your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You've taken button type **submit** so when you click on Submit button page will simply redirect to **dashboard.php** instead of ajax call. so change button tag like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">Login</button>
```